# The given path's format is not supported when reading a Json file

Tags: c#, json, wpf

I am trying to read a Json file and deserialize it. But whenver I try to read the file it says "The given path's format is not supported". Here is my json file. Before posting I went through this post but i guess it dosen't relate to my problem[The given path's format is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38010414/the-given-paths-format-is-not-supported-c-sharp)

Editing my post here is the structure of the project. Main Solution -> ViewModels (folder) -> DGXRun.json

```
{
    "type": "DGX parameter file",
    "version": "v1.0",
    "date": "01/10/2018",

    "assays": [
        {
            "assay_1": {
                "display_name": "W3 single cell V1.0",
                "volumes": [
                    {
                        "volume_1": {
                            "volume_display_value": 20,
                            "global_parameters": {
                                "param1": 5
                            },
                            "run": {
                                "Initialize coarse reservoirs": {
                                    "Max time": 30.0,
                                    "Min time": 5.0,
                                    "Set temperature": 22.0,
                                    "Air flow min": 0,
                                    "Air flow max": 0,
                                    "Vacuum Reservoir Pressure": -5.0,
                                    "Pressure Reservoir Pressure": 5.0,
                                    "Channel 1 Pressure": 0.0,
                                    "Channel 2 Pressure": 0.0,
                                    "Channel 3 Pressure": 0.0,
                                    "Channel 4 Pressure": -1.75,
                                    "V13:Channel 1OutletValve": "Closed",
                                    "V14:Channel 2OutletValve": "Closed",
                                    "V15:Channel 3 Outlet Valve": "Closed",
                                    "V16:Channel 4 Outlet Valve": "Closed",
                                    "V17:Channel 1 Small Large Valve": "Small",
                                    "V18:Channel 2 Small Large Valve": "Small",
                                    "V19:Channel 3 Small Large Valve": "Small"
                                },
                                "Create droplets": {
                                    "Max time": 180.0,
                                    "Min time": 180.0,
                                    "Set temperature": 22.0,
                                    "Air flow min": 0,
                                    "Air flow max": 2,
                                    "Vacuum Reservoir Pressure": -5.0,
                                    "Pressure Reservoir Pressure": 5.0,
                                    "Channel 1 Pressure": 0.0,
                                    "Channel 2 Pressure": 0.0,
                                    "Channel 3 Pressure": 0.0,
                                    "Channel 4 Pressure": -1.75,
                                    "V13: Channel 1 Outlet Valve": "Closed",
                                    "V14: Channel 2 Outlet Valve": "Closed",
                                    "V15: Channel 3 Outlet Valve": "Closed",
                                    "V16: Channel 4 Outlet Valve": "Open",
                                    "V17: Channel 1 Small Large Valve": "Small",
                                    "V18: Channel 2 Small Large Valve": "Small",
                                    "V19: Channel 3 Small Large Valve": "Small"
                                },
                                "Initialize Pushback": {
                                    "Max time": 5.0,
                                    "Min time": 1.0,
                                    "Set temperature": 22.0,
                                    "Air flow min": 0,
                                    "Air flow max": 0,
                                    "Vacuum Reservoir Pressure": -5.0,
                                    "Pressure Reservoir Pressure": 5.0,
                                    "Channel 1 Pressure": 0.0,
                                    "Channel 2 Pressure": 0.0,
                                    "Channel 3 Pressure": 0.0,
                                    "Channel 4 Pressure": 2.0,
                                    "V13: Channel 1 Outlet Valve": "Closed",
                                    "V14: Channel 2 Outlet Valve": "Closed",
                                    "V15: Channel 3 Outlet Valve": "Closed",
                                    "V16: Channel 4 Outlet Valve": "Closed",
                                    "V17: Channel 1 Small Large Valve": "Small",
                                    "V18: Channel 2 Small Large Valve": "Small",
                                    "V19: Channel 3 Small Large Valve": "Small"
                                },
                                "Pushback": {
                                    "Max time": 25.0,
                                    "Min time": 25.0,
                                    "Set temperature": 22.0,
                                    "Air flow min": 0,
                                    "Air flow max": 0,
                                    "Vacuum Reservoir Pressure": -5.0,
                                    "Pressure Reservoir Pressure": 5.0,
                                    "Channel 1 Pressure": 0.0,
                                    "Channel 2 Pressure": 0.0,
                                    "Channel 3 Pressure": 0.0,
                                    "Channel 4 Pressure": 2.0,
                                    "V13: Channel 1 Outlet Valve": "Closed",
                                    "V14: Channel 2 Outlet Valve": "Closed",
                                    "V15: Channel 3 Outlet Valve": "Closed",
                                    "V16: Channel 4 Outlet Valve": "Open",
                                    "V17: Channel 1 Small Large Valve": "Small",
                                    "V18: Channel 2 Small Large Valve": "Small",
                                    "V19: Channel 3 Small Large Valve": "Small"
                                },
                                "End": {
                                    "Max time": 5.0,
                                    "Min time": 1.0,
                                    "Set temperature": 22.0,
                                    "Air flow min": 0,
                                    "Air flow max": 0,
                                    "Vacuum Reservoir Pressure": 0.0,
                                    "Pressure Reservoir Pressure": 0.0,
                                    "Channel 1 Pressure": 0.0,
                                    "Channel 2 Pressure": 0.0,
                                    "Channel 3 Pressure": 0.0,
                                    "Channel 4 Pressure": 0.0,
                                    "V13: Channel 1 Outlet Valve": "Closed",
                                    "V14: Channel 2 Outlet Valve": "Closed",
                                    "V15: Channel 3 Outlet Valve": "Closed",
                                    "V16: Channel 4 Outlet Valve": "Closed",
                                    "V17: Channel 1 Small Large Valve": "Small",
                                    "V18: Channel 2 Small Large Valve": "Small",
                                    "V19: Channel 3 Small Large Valve": "Small"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "volume_2": {
                            "volume_display_value": 50,
                            "global_parameters": {
                                "param1": 5
                            },
                            "run": {
                                "Step 1": {
                                    "Max time": 30.0,
                                    "Min time": 5.0,
                                    "Set temperature": 22.0,
                                    "Air flow min": 0,
                                    "Air flow max": 0,
                                    "Vacuum Reservoir Pressure": -5.0,
                                    "Pressure Reservoir Pressure": 5.0,
                                    "Channel 1 Pressure": 0.0,
                                    "Channel 2 Pressure": 0.0,
                                    "Channel 3 Pressure": 0.0,
                                    "Channel 4 Pressure": -1.75,
                                    "V13: Channel 1 Outlet Valve": "Closed",
                                    "V14: Channel 2 Outlet Valve": "Closed",
                                    "V15: Channel 3 Outlet Valve": "Closed",
                                    "V16: Channel 4 Outlet Valve": "Closed",
                                    "V17: Channel 1 Small Large Valve": "Small",
                                    "V18: Channel 2 Small Large Valve": "Small",
                                    "V19: Channel 3 Small Large Valve": "Small"
                                },
                                "Step 2": {
                                    "Max time": 180.0,
                                    "Min time": 180.0,
                                    "Set temperature": 22.0,
                                    "Air flow min": 0,
                                    "Air flow max": 2,
                                    "Vacuum Reservoir Pressure": -5.0,
                                    "Pressure Reservoir Pressure": 5.0,
                                    "Channel 1 Pressure": 0.0,
                                    "Channel 2 Pressure": 0.0,
                                    "Channel 3 Pressure": 0.0,
                                    "Channel 4 Pressure": -1.75,
                                    "V13: Channel 1 Outlet Valve": "Closed",
                                    "V14: Channel 2 Outlet Valve": "Closed",
                                    "V15: Channel 3 Outlet Valve": "Closed",
                                    "V16: Channel 4 Outlet Valve": "Open",
                                    "V17: Channel 1 Small Large Valve": "Small",
                                    "V18: Channel 2 Small Large Valve": "Small",
                                    "V19: Channel 3 Small Large Valve": "Small"
                                },
                                "Step 3": {
                                    "Max time": 5.0,
                                    "Min time": 1.0,
                                    "Set temperature": 22.0,
                                    "Air flow min": 0,
                                    "Air flow max": 0,
                                    "Vacuum Reservoir Pressure": -5.0,
                                    "Pressure Reservoir Pressure": 5.0,
                                    "Channel 1 Pressure": 0.0,
                                    "Channel 2 Pressure": 0.0,
                                    "Channel 3 Pressure": 0.0,
                                    "Channel 4 Pressure": 2.0,
                                    "V13: Channel 1 Outlet Valve": "Closed",
                                    "V14: Channel 2 Outlet Valve": "Closed",
                                    "V15: Channel 3 Outlet Valve": "Closed",
                                    "V16: Channel 4 Outlet Valve": "Closed",
                                    "V17: Channel 1 Small Large Valve": "Small",
                                    "V18: Channel 2 Small Large Valve": "Small",
                                    "V19: Channel 3 Small Large Valve": "Small"
                                },
                                "Step 4": {
                                    "Max time": 25.0,
                                    "Min time": 25.0,
                                    "Set temperature": 22.0,
                                    "Air flow min": 0,
                                    "Air flow max": 0,
                                    "Vacuum Reservoir Pressure": -5.0,
                                    "Pressure Reservoir Pressure": 5.0,
                                    "Channel 1 Pressure": 0.0,
                                    "Channel 2 Pressure": 0.0,
                                    "Channel 3 Pressure": 0.0,
                                    "Channel 4 Pressure": 2.0,
                                    "V13: Channel 1 Outlet Valve": "Closed",
                                    "V14: Channel 2 Outlet Valve": "Closed",
                                    "V15: Channel 3 Outlet Valve": "Closed",
                                    "V16: Channel 4 Outlet Valve": "Open",
                                    "V17: Channel 1 Small Large Valve": "Small",
                                    "V18: Channel 2 Small Large Valve": "Small",
                                    "V19: Channel 3 Small Large Valve": "Small"
                                },
                                "Step 5": {
                                    "Max time": 5.0,
                                    "Min time": 1.0,
                                    "Set temperature": 22.0,
                                    "Air flow min": 0,
                                    "Air flow max": 0,
                                    "Vacuum Reservoir Pressure": 0.0,
                                    "Pressure Reservoir Pressure": 0.0,
                                    "Channel 1 Pressure": 0.0,
                                    "Channel 2 Pressure": 0.0,
                                    "Channel 3 Pressure": 0.0,
                                    "Channel 4 Pressure": 0.0,
                                    "V13: Channel 1 Outlet Valve": "Closed",
                                    "V14: Channel 2 Outlet Valve": "Closed",
                                    "V15: Channel 3 Outlet Valve": "Closed",
                                    "V16: Channel 4 Outlet Valve": "Closed",
                                    "V17: Channel 1 Small Large Valve": "Small",
                                    "V18: Channel 2 Small Large Valve": "Small",
                                    "V19: Channel 3 Small Large Valve": "Small"
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                ]
            },

            "assay_2": {
                "display_name": "W3 single cell V2.0",
                "volumes": [
                    {
                        "volume_1": {
                            "volume display value": 100,
                            "global parameters": {
                                "param1": 0
                            },
                            "run": {
                            }
                        }

                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This is how I am trying to read it,

```
string json = File.ReadAllText("pack://application:,,,/BioRad.NextGenDG.ViewModels;component/DGXRun.json"); //I get an exception here.
            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReadJsonAssays>(json);
```

Comment: The error message does not have anything to do with your JSON file.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that `File.ReadAllText` is meant to be used on filesystem paths only. I don't recognize the "pack://..." etc. path, and I'm guessing that's where `File.ReadAllText` is choking too. If you can read the contents of that file some other way (for instance with `WebClient`?) then you should be able to pass the contents into `DeserializeObject`